# In My Favorite Martian, why couldn't Uncle Martin just call for help or a tow?

Tags: my-favorite-martian

The 1960s TV series *My Favorite Martian* follows the adventures of a centuries old, humanoid Martian traveler who got stranded on earth when his spaceship was damaged. The martian is a historian who has visted Earth many times before, documenting numerous occurrences, and ended up staying with the human bachelor, Tim, who tried to help him when his ship was damaged on this last visit. Going by the alias "Uncle Martin", the alien is shown to have unique biology and impressive powers, most stemming from his "highly advanced brain", which range from inventing incredible machines to levitation of objects and matter manipulation. The  base scenery is that Martin *cannot leave* the planet until his space ship is repaired. But if that was the case [plot needs aside]...

Why didn't Martin simply make a communication device and use *that* to call home to Mars for someone to come and either get him the necessary parts to repair his ship, or just bring him back home?

Was there an episode, perhaps, where this possibility was explored?

Comment: 'My favorite Martian' was a television series broadcast between 1963 and 1966. 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial' was produced for a theatre venue and wasn't released until 1982. Even if you discard the tv-to-movie disparity, that's at least  a full 16 years between painted styrofoam set props.

Comment: If memory serves, Martin was an anthropologist and extremely long-lived. He probably viewed this delay in fixing his ship as an opportunity to spend some time with the locals and no more problematic than swapping a blown tyre

Comment: @Valorum You are very correct about him being an anthropologist; thanks for the correction. Wrong about the "no more problematic than swapping a blown tire" bit; as early as episode 3, he's seen repairing the ship and says "its a slow processes; there are rare elements I'm missing,"  and "I need things you earthlings haven't invented yet." So it wasn't all the way voluntary for him to be here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of if the answer is what you're looking for, but I believe it is true and accurate.

Walter Tevis, the American English Professor and Novelist, wrote "The Man Who Fell to Earth" (TMWFTE) which had its 1st printing in February 1963. I believe there was an advance readers copy (ARC) available for book reviewers before it went to press.

The first episode of "My Favorite Martian" aired on September 29, 1963.

The protagonist, Thomas Jerome Newton, of TMWFTE is an alien who has landed on Earth, but his ship is unable to return, thus he has to raise hundreds of millions of dollars to fund a project to build a spaceship for him to return to his home planet. He is incredibly advanced in technology, yet he is unable to communicate with his family on his home planet, which is dying. Thus he has to get back with his own resourcefulness and ingenuity.

This aspect of the plot, that he is responsible for his own salvation (returning to his home planet), is tellingly similar to "My Favorite Martian" which was written soon afterwards.

The second, although more prosaic, reason is probably because it is a plot device. If it was easy to for Uncle Martin to "phone home" and he was delivered from the Earth by his kind then there would be no need for any further TV episodes, let alone further TV seasons.

There was another TV series which aired in 1966-1967 with 26 episodes called "It's About Time" (Absolutely fantastic with a catchy theme song, link follows). The premise was two American astronauts who get lost, not in space, but in time. They wind up crashing on Earth in the time of the cavemen. Why is this important? If you listen to the lyrics, towards the very end, it gives the Answer... which is, "Watch each week and see." Being stuck, as a Stranger in a Strange Land, is a plot device. That's the answer.

*Where will they go?*

*What will they do?*

*In this strange place where everything is new.*

*Will they manage to survive?*

***Watch each week and see.***

*Will they get accustomed to the Twentieth Century?*

source: http://www.lyricsondemand.com/tvthemes/itsabouttimelyrics.html

---

[Theme Song From the TV Series "It's About Time"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsJhBn0I9U4)

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Was an interesting comparative and bit of trivia though. I did acknowledge the whole "plot device" effect earlier, though, but the idea of Martin _needing_ to be responsible for his own slavation due to some type of possible fall out on Mars was a good one. Very interesting, EarthBorne. Thank you for the new perspective.